# Laravel Model::all() or Model::get problem

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a project with a database

then i do dd on controller while doing model::get() or model::all()

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaBn8.png)

then i get the result i want like in the first picture

the problem starts from when i create a new project with the same database and the same code, i do model::all() or model::get() but what i get is the result like in the second picture, what should i do to get results like my first project?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHfhK.png)

and thats my problem, how can i get output like picture one? sorry for my bad i am a newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
model::all()->toArray();
```