# Error Call to a member function where() on array Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to do filtering from the data that I display, but there is a problem when I add where to my data.

the plan in the future I want to add if isset $request name, date and others. but was constrained at this one point.

Thank you for helping to answer in advance

```
    $matchs =Matchs::where('type', 'sparring')->where('status','Pending')->whereNull('deleted_at')->get()->toArray();
    $data=[];
    foreach ($matchs as $key) {
        $lawan = Matchs::where('id', $key['id'])->first()->ToArray();
        $pertandingan = Sparring::where('match_id', $key['id'])->first()->ToArray();
        $dua_arah = MatchTwoTeam::where('match_id', $key['id'])->first()->ToArray();
        $tim =  Team::where('id', $dua_arah['home_team'])->first()->ToArray();


                $transfer['name']=$tim['name'];
                $transfer['city']=$lawan['city'];
                $transfer['field_cost']=$pertandingan['field_cost'];
                $transfer['referee_cost']=$pertandingan['referee_cost'];
                $transfer['logo_path']=$tim['logo_path'];
                $transfer['nama_lapangan']=$lawan['nama_lapangan'];
                $transfer['date']=$lawan['date'];
                array_push($data,$transfer);  
        array_push($data,$pertandingan);  
    
    }
    $data->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.'football'.'%')->get()->toArray();
    $data = array_search('football', array_column($data, 'name'));
    $tittle="Sparring";
    return view('mode.sparring',[
        'tittle' => $tittle,
        'data' => $data,
    ]);
```

Comment: `$data` is an array but you're trying to call `where` on in. It's also really bad practice/inefficient to load models inside a loop. Do you have relationships set up for `Sparring` and `MatchTwoTeam` in your `Matchs` model?

Comment: I don't have it, I created a new project with the old database. Previously I had a problem with getting data ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70133457/laravel-modelall-or-modelget-problem ), I hope you can help me who is a beginner

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call `where` in an array which is not possible.

As you can see in the first line of your code you are calling `where` method in your model class. Like `Matchs::where('type', 'sparring')`, this is possible because `Matchs` is a Model class.

Now you can run where even if you are using array. You can convert that day in collection and then use array on that collection.
As below:

```
collect($data)->where('name', 'football')->toArray();
```

Here `collect()` will convert the `$data` array to collectio and then run the `where()` method in collectio then `toArray()` will change it back to array. But unfortunately there is no `like` operator possible in collection class. See the list of available method in Laravel collection here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods

There is a way to do what you are trying to do. As far as I understand you want to filter the `Matches` where the `Team` name has `footbal` in it. You can do it like this:

```
Matchs::where('type', 'sparring')
  ->where('status','Pending')
  ->whereNull('deleted_at')
  ->whereHas('team', function($team) {
    return $team->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.'football'.'%')
  })
  ->get()
  ->toArray();
```

So, here we can get the only those `Mathes` that has the `Team` that has the name contains `football`.

Few suggestion for you as seems you are new in Laravel:

1. Model name should be singular instead of plural, so the model class `Matchs` should be `Match`. Your name for team's model is `Team` is correct.
2. Avoid using `toArray()` because you won't need it. When you call `get()` it will return object of collection which more readable and powerful then array in most cases.
3. The code I suggested to use the `like` using `whereHas` will only work if you have propery defined your `team` relation in your `Matchs` class. So, defining your relationships in model is also important. If you do so, you don't even need the `for` loop and all those `where` in other model in that loop. You can do it in one query with all the relationships.